# Why isn't Google Chrome showing the proper encoding?

Tags: google-chrome

I'm sorry if this isn't the right place to be posting a question like this, but I'm at wit's end trying to figure out an answer. I don't know if it's an encoding issue or what, but on SO many web pages, Chrome won't display some characters properly. Namely things like en and em dashes, elipses, etc.

Here's an example.

[image: encoding example]

That O with the umlaut is supposed to be an ellipses. I don't see the problem on Firefox, and I don't see the problem on another computer with Chrome. Encoding is set to Auto-Detect and UTF-8. If I copy and paste the O with the umlaut, it pastes as an ellipses.

Any idea why this is happening and how I can fix it?

Comment: By the way, Chrome is updated to the latest version, and I've tried disabling all extensions and reloading with no luck.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

If it pastes back as the expected character, then it is not an encoding problem - it rather would be a font problem: you likely have a font installed in your system that is being used by Chrome to display S.O.  (and possibly other pages' text). If this font is broken (like, it has an incorrect encoding declaration itself), this could happen.

The workaround is finding out which is the offensive font and uninstall it from your system.

Comment: You got it. I'll accept this as the right answer as soon as I can. Thanks! Found the offending font by right clicking and Inspecting Element and looking at the call it was making. Deleted the offending font, and it worked as expected. Thanks!

Comment: this is not the right answer, see [user1990310] post for right answer

Comment: @dns: "find out the offensive font and uninstall it" against "Select the universal copy of Arial and deactivate it." are about the same thing, just the other answer lists the specific font which is broken for some users.

Comment: @jsbueno No. You didn't read the right comment. dns is right. Check user1990310's reply. This is nothing to do with fonts. It's to do with how Chrome options are set.

Comment: Another nice trick to check if is a rendering font problem is go to *Inspect Element* on the wrong displayed text. Then, in the first style box (**element.style**) add: *font-family: arial;* or whatever different font. Instantlly the text will be rendered with this new font.

Comment: @jsbueno your answer is correct in my case too. In certain updated version of Chrome, one of the html entity of 'hyphen' stopped to be encoded. The font family is same but after the Chrome upgrade, anyhow it stopped to show the entity after encoding. It has given me an idea to set a fallback font-family to ensure 'proper' encoding of the html entity. Now, it's working fine. Thank you for your post.

Answer (score 4):

I had the problem with Chrome on Mac OSX.7.5 using Universal Type Client.

In Chrome go to pop-out side menu (3 horizontal bars) > Tools > Encoding and set the page to Auto-detect, UTF-8 (you should switch auto-detect off if it's slowing the browser down).

In Universal Type Client, there was 2 versions of Arial in conflict with each other.

Select the universal copy of Arial and deactivate it.

All pages now render correctly in Chrome.

Answer (score 1):

I have a similar problem. But the thing is, the writing on the websites displays fine. It is just the writing in the Google Chrome tab that doesn't show. It comes up with squares. To fix this, I had to change the encoding to Auto-Detect and UTF-8 (I have to deselect it and then select it again). Then restart my computer in order for the writing in the tabs to display.

However, I find that the next time I turn on my computer, I have to go through the same process and it's quite irritating. Has anyone else had this problem and if so, how do we work about this?

Cheers,
C

Answer (score 0):

This has been driving me bananas too.  The resolution for me was similar to pho3nix's answer; but rather than creating local stylesheet overrides I removed Helvetica Neue Regular from my system.  Call me a snob but better than mapping it to Aerial :-)

There was no need to remove Helvetica Neue Condensed, Light or other variants.  Somehow Chrome chooses Helvetica Neue Regular to render Helvetica Regular if you have it installed.

There seems to be a problem with the way (at least some) Helvetica Neue font files have been mapped that makes them unsuitable for displaying in a browser but OK in Photoshop or Illustratior.